# What's the difference between 'voices that care' and ' caring voices'?

Tags: difference

I want to know the difference between 'voices that care' and ' caring voices' in meaning.
Please, tell me the difference in meaning.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in meaning.

Comment: What @P.E.Dant said in his comment-which-is-actually-an-answer -_- ... If that's not what you're looking for, providing context would help.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases have the same meaning.

If I was to make a distinction, "caring voices" could describe people with a gentle reassuring tone of voice, and "voices that care" could refer to people prepared to speak out against an injustice.

btw I am British.